# Can I override the color of default header and the footer

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I am a newbie react native developer. I am currently working on Android and I am using the Pixel XL API P AVD.

So far my app screen looks like this. 
[image]

Will it be possible for me to override the "grey" header and the "black" footer with colors of my app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the component [`StatusBar`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/statusbar.html).

Just make sure to add it above your navigator styles or other component

```
  <StatusBar
     backgroundColor="blue"
     barStyle="light-content"
   />
   // Navigators
```

For **Navbar color** , you may consider using [this](https://github.com/BhavanPatel/react-native-navbar-color) package.

and use it as `NavigationBar.setColor('#ffab8e')`